# PHP sqrt() returns NAN

Tags: php, nan

I've written a piece of code to carry out the quadratic equation:

```
function quadratic($a,$b,$c) {
    $mb = $b - ($b*2);
    $bs = $b * $b;
    $fac = ($a * $c) * 4;

    $ans1 = ($mb + sqrt(($bs - $fac))) / (2 * $a);
    $ans2 = ($mb - sqrt(($bs - $fac))) / (2 * $a);

    echo ("Your <b>+</b> value is: " . $ans1 . "<br />");
    echo ("Your <b>-</b> value is: " . $ans2);
}
```

The problem is that, if for example a=2, b=4, c=8, both answers are outputted as NAN. Any ideas as to how to fix this so that I get an actual number output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If interested in having a "real number" solution, see:

```
function quadratic($a,$b,$c) {
    $mb = $b - ($b*2);
    $bs = $b * $b;
    $fac = ($a * $c) * 4;

    $bsfac = $bs-$fac;
    if($bsfac < 0){
        $bsfac *= -1;
    }

    $ans1 = ($mb + sqrt(($bsfac))) / (2 * $a);
    $ans2 = ($mb - sqrt(($bsfac))) / (2 * $a);

    echo ("Your <b>+</b> value is: " . $ans1 . "<br />");
    echo ("Your <b>-</b> value is: " . $ans2);
}
```

*Rounding not included

Comment: `if($bsfac < 0){$bsfac *= -1;}` is equivalent to `abs($bsfac)`, or in this case, `abs($bs - $fac)`

Comment: the function should somehow indicate that the solution is a complex number, otherwise it is not correct

Answer (score 7):

```
   $a * $c * 4 = 64
   $bs = 4 * 4 = 16
   sqrt(($bs - $fac))) = sqrt(-48)
```

You cant take the sqrt of a negative number, it is not defined, hence the result is NaN.

Futhermore your formula can be simplified as:

```
 $mb = $b - ($b*2) = -$b
```

So instad of `$mb` you can simply use `-$b`.

Besides that, your formula is correct for the quadratic equation.

Comment: That is not completely correct. The number does not exist in the real number system, but it is in the complex system (`sqrt(-48)` = `6.9i`)

Comment: PHP doesn't have "complex system" rules, then. According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqrt.php... "Return Values

The square root of arg or the special value NAN for negative numbers."

Comment: true, it is a complex number, but I'm quite sure the OP is interested in a real number solution

Comment: I am. So is there no way to output the -decimal?

Comment: no, the formula has no solution for your input in the real number space, only one in complex number space where a square root of a negative number is signified with a multiplication of i=sqrt(-1), see Blakes solution for that

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping in these lines.

```
    $ans1 = ($mb + sqrt(abs($bs - $fac))) / (2 * $a);
    $ans2 = ($mb - sqrt(abs($bs - $fac))) / (2 * $a);
```

Comment: Why's that, @pivotnig? Heh, when I was using php to do my math homework years ago, my teacher never said my answers were wrong using `sqrt(abs())`! What's the issue with it?